# Libgdx smooth horizontal scroll images

Tags: libgdx

I have below setup for purchasing items in my game:

[image]

As you can see, if I have more than 3 items the user should be able to scroll to see the next item. So far, I have tried to use `Actor`'s event like `TouchDrag`. However there is a glitch during the interaction, like it won't scroll until my finger reach the left side of each image.. Do you guys have any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ScrollPane](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ScrollPane.html) actor, it has all the functionality you need and you can create your own `UI elements` for it. You could add a table to it with all your buttons, widgets and other actors and it will handle all the scrolling for you.